# Mongoose aggregate won't work while same query in mongo shell does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to fetch some stuff from my mongoDB using mongoose.model.aggregate, however, it keeps returning empty object.

I'm running the query in Node v13.8.0 environment.

The aggregate query is the following:

```
db.getCollection("marketoffers").aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    crawledAt: 1584713771908 //req.params thingy
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$items",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "locales",
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          lang: "en"
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "localization"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$localization",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    "items.localizationData": {
      $filter: {
        input: {
          $objectToArray: "$localization.data"
        },
        cond: {
          $eq: ["$$this.k", "$items._tpl"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$items.localizationData",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    requirementsInfo: {
      $map: {
        input: "$requirements",
        as: "bidule",
        in: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$localization.data"
            },
            as: "truc",
            cond: {
              $eq: ["$$truc.k", "$$bidule._tpl"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "items.localizationData.k": 0.0,
    localization: 0.0
  }
} ]);
```

This aggregate works in mongo shell, and gives me the results, however, if i try to run it with mongoose.model.aggregate, it doesn't work:

```
      let test = Models.MarketOffer.aggregate([
    { $match: config }, //config is basically an object: {crawledAt: 1584713771908 }
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$items",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "locales",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              lang: "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "localization"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$localization",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "items.localizationData": {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$localization.data"
            },
            cond: {
              $eq: ["$$this.k", "$items._tpl"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$items.localizationData",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        requirementsInfo: {
          $map: {
            input: "$requirements",
            as: "bidule",
            in: {
              $filter: {
                input: {
                  $objectToArray: "$localization.data"
                },
                as: "truc",
                cond: {
                  $eq: ["$$truc.k", "$$bidule._tpl"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "items.localizationData.k": 0.0,
        localization: 0.0
      }
    }
  ]);
```

I tried with aggregate.exec(), with and without awaiting it etc, same result.

The collection is named MarketOffers and has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e73ffd034e8d20025649014"),
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "5e7396dfdcb4c11e5c2206c5",
            "_tpl": "5672cb124bdc2d1a0f8b4568",
            "upd": {
                "Resource": {
                    "Value": 0
                },
                "StackObjectsCount": 106
            }
        }
    ],
    "requirements": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "_tpl": "56742c284bdc2d98058b456d"
        }
    ],
    "intId": 18465852853,
    "root": "5e7396dfdcb4c11e5c2206c5",
    "itemsCost": 652,
    "requirementsCost": 244,
    "sellInOnePiece": false,
    "startTime": 1584633567,
    "endTime": 1585832367,
    "loyaltyLevel": 1,
    "_tarkov_id": "5e7396dfdcb4c11e5c2206c68",
    "crawledAt": 1584650951344,
    "categoryName": "Energy elements",
    "categoryID": "5b47574386f77428ca22b2ed"
}
```

Models.MarketOffer is a mongoose.model constructed as such:

```
//marketoffer.ts
const MarketOfferSchema = new Schema(
    {//properties here},
    {versionKey: '0.1'});

// MarketOfferSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
// must match the MarketOffers collection
MarketOfferSchema.plugin(aggregatePaginate);

export const MarketOffer = () => {
  return mongoose.model<any>('MarketOffer', MarketOfferSchema);
}
```

And used in the Model class:

```
//models.ts
import { SingleItem as s } from "./Item";
import { MarketOffer as m } from "./MarketOffer";

import { Locale as l } from "./Locale";

// TODO singleton
class Models {
  SingleItem;
  MarketOffer;
  Locale;
  constructor() {
    this.SingleItem = s();
    this.MarketOffer = m();
    this.Locale = l();
  }
}
export default new Models();
```

Not really used to mongoose so any help would be appreciated :)

Let me know if you need additional details !

Comment: Try to change `Models.MarketOffer` to `var MarketOffer = mongoose.model('MarketOffer', yourSchema); //or connection.model('MarketOffer', yourSchema); let test = MarketOffer.aggregate(...).exec();`

Comment: updated first post: i can't find how to post formatted code here